# How does one find the mouse X and Y coordinates relative to a JPanel? (Java)

Tags: java, jpanel, mouse, mouselistener

I'm creating a program where the JPanel is bigger than the JFrame, and as a result it scrolls left, right, up, and down. In my program, I'm trying to find the mouse's X and Y coordinates **relative to the JPanel**. When I add a MouseListener to the JPanel (called GraphicsPanel), the listener seems to find the X and Y coordinates of the mouse relative to the JFrame. I've been searching for hours on this, and I would really appreciate some help! Thanks!

Main Method:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Main extends JFrame {
//Game Panel Creation
private JPanel gamePanel;

//Frame Y-Coordinate Offset (Due to the menu bar at the top of frame)
public static int frameHeightOffset = 23;

//Frame Width, Height
public static int frameWidth = 784, frameHeight = frameWidth + frameHeightOffset;

//Game Panel Width, Height
public static int graphicsPanelWidth = 896, graphicsPanelHeight = 896;

//Main Setup
public Main(){
    //JFrame Setup
    super("Pixel Wars");
    setSize(new Dimension(frameWidth, frameHeight));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);

    //Game Panel Setup
    gamePanel = new GraphicsPanel(graphicsPanelWidth, graphicsPanelHeight);
    gamePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(graphicsPanelWidth, graphicsPanelHeight));
    gamePanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(graphicsPanelWidth, graphicsPanelHeight));


    //Adding Listeners
    addKeyListener(new ActionKeyListener());
    gamePanel.addMouseListener(new ActionMouseListener());

    //Adding Game Panel to JFrame
    add(gamePanel);
    setVisible(true);
}

//Main Method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
}
```

Mouse Listener:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ActionMouseListener implements MouseListener{
private int mouseX, mouseY;
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event){
    mouseX = event.getX();
    mouseY = event.getY();

    if(mouseX >= GraphicsPanel.castle_red.getX() && mouseX <= GraphicsPanel.castle_red.getX() + (GraphicsPanel.blockSize * 5) && mouseY >= GraphicsPanel.castle_red.getY() && mouseY <= GraphicsPanel.castle_red.getY() + (GraphicsPanel.blockSize * 5)){
        GraphicsPanel.peasantList.add(new Peasant(new Random().nextInt(400)+100, new Random().nextInt(400)+100));
        System.out.println(mouseX + ", " + mouseY);
    } else {

    }
}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){

}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event){

}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event){

}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event){

}
```

}

Graphics Panel (JPanel):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel {
//Game Panel Width, Height
private int width, height;

//Game Camera Setup
public static Camera gameCamera = new Camera(0, 0);

//Grid Block Setup
public static int blockSize = 16;
private int gridX, gridY;
public static ArrayList<Block> blockList = new ArrayList<Block>();

//Castles Setup
public static Castle castle_red, castle_blue;

//Peasant Setup
public static ArrayList<Peasant> peasantList = new ArrayList<Peasant>();

//Graphics Panel Setup
public GraphicsPanel(int width, int height){
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    setSize(width, height);
}

//Paint Component
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

    //Camera Motion
    g2.translate(-gameCamera.getX(), -gameCamera.getY());

    //Map Creator
    blockList.clear();
    gridY = -16;
    for(int rows = 0; rows < height; rows += blockSize){
        gridX = 0;
        gridY += blockSize;
        for(int columns = 0; columns < width; columns += blockSize){
            blockList.add(new Block(gridX, gridY));
            gridX += blockSize;
        }
    }

    //Block Creator
    for(int i = 0; i < blockList.size(); i++){
        blockList.get(i).drawGrass(g2);
    }

    //Castle Creator
    castle_red = new Castle(blockSize, blockSize);
    castle_red.draw(g2, new ImageIcon("/Users/student/PixelWars/src/Resources/castle_red.png"));

    castle_blue = new Castle(width-(blockSize*6), height-(blockSize*6));
    castle_blue.draw(g2, new ImageIcon("/Users/student/PixelWars/src/Resources/castle_blue.png"));

    //Peasant Creator
    for(int i = 0; i < peasantList.size(); i++){
        peasantList.get(i).draw(g2, new ImageIcon("/Users/student/PixelWars/src/Resources/peasant_front.png"));
    }

    //Frame Rate Setup
    Timer frameRate = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            repaint();
        }
    });
    frameRate.start();
}
```

}

Comment: How are you scrolling the contents of the `GraphicsPanel`? In fact, what does the `GraphicsPanel` look like? Based on the limited information, it would suggest that the panel is actually smaller in size then the frame

Comment: Oops! I just added the JPanel. Actually, the JPanel is bigger than the frame, and the program scrolls via the W, A, S, and D keys.

Comment: Given the frame (or contentPane) is probably changing the size of panel to fit into the frame based on the use of BorderLayout

Comment: Based on what I can understand, you’ll need to translate the mouse x/y (world) by the gameCamera x/y (virtual) coordinates

Comment: I've been searching and trying and I still can't figure this out! @MadProgrammer do you have any ideas on how to translate the mouse x to the gameCamera x and with the y's as well?

Comment: The `gameCamera` is translating the offset of the virtual world to the real world. You need to apply the same translation to the mouse event

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks so much! It was easier to translate the offset than I thought!